# Need to prepare queries based on batch size

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary with key and a list if model as values like below as example data:

```
var dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Model>>
        {
            {
                "X1", new List<Model>
                {
                    new Model { Name = "N1"},
                    new Model { Name = "N2"},
                    new Model { Name = "N3"}
                }
            },
            {
                "X2", new List<Model>
                {
                    new Model { Name = "N1"},
                }
            }
        };
```

In above example I have `3+1 = 4` models.

Here are my requirements:

- if batch size = 2, then I need to prepare 2 queries from all 4 items.

  ```
    (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N1),
    (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N2),


    (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N3),
    (SELECT * FROM X2 WHERE Name = N1),
  ```
- if batch size = 4 or above, then I need to prepare 1 query from all 4 items.

  ```
   (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N1),
   (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N2),
   (SELECT * FROM X1 WHERE Name = N3),
   (SELECT * FROM X2 WHERE Name = N1),
  ```

Below is my try, but for batch size = 2, it's giving me 3 queries, how to aggregate both `X1` and `X2` data and generate only 2 queries for all 4 items?

```
var queries = new List<string>();

foreach (var (key, value) in dataDictionary)
{
    foreach (var lstModel in value.Batch(2))
    {
        var query = string.Empty;

        foreach (var val in lstModel)
        {
            query += $"(SELECT * FROM {key} WHERE Name = {val.Name}),";
        }

        queries.Add(query);
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is my model and extension class,

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int maxItems)
    {
        return items.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
            .GroupBy(x => x.inx / maxItems)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try using the [Modulo(%) Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to calculate the remainder and use that instead of `x.inx / maxItems`, it may yield more intuitive results.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use some kind of Table parameter (unclear what database DBMS you are using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Flattening your dictionary into simple IEnumerable and then batching it according to your batch size.

```
var BATCH_SIZE = 4;
var queries = new List<string>();

var items = dataDictionary.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value.Select(model => Tuple.Create(kv.Key, model)));

var currentbatchSize = 0;
var batchedQuery = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in items)
{
            batchedQuery += $"(SELECT * FROM {item.Item1} WHERE Name = {item.Item2.Name}),";

            if (currentbatchSize == BATCH_SIZE - 1)
            {
                queries.Add(batchedQuery);
                batchedQuery = string.Empty;
                currentbatchSize = 0;
                continue;
            }

            currentbatchSize++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought same and looking if we don't need to Flattening the dictionary into simple IEnumerable :(